# Is it bad data design to duplicate Rails associations?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Let's say I have a Rails 3 application with the following model associations:

```
user
  belongs_to :group

item
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user
```

If code is not carefully written, this can result in data discrepancies where:

item.group

and

item.user.group

no longer return the same group, when they should. An item should always only belong to only 1 group.

My understanding is that this duplicate association may have been created to make querying simpler (reduce the number of tables joined).

So my question is, is this just an outright terrible practice or is this a question of valid trade-offs, that there are cases where the data and association duplication are acceptable because we can make querying simpler with fewer joins.

UPDATE

So far seems like the answer is "trade offs" and not "bad practice/code smell".

There seems to be multiple ways this can be handled, probably with a mix of constraints, advantages, disadvantages, use cases, etc:

1) denormalized, duplicated data as above
2) item has_one :group, :through => :user
3) item delegate :group :to => :user

I'm trying to understand the differences between approach #2 and #3. After experimenting with both approaches in the console, seems like the queries produced by Rails when item.group is called will be different. (2) produces a single query that joins groups and users. (2) produces two queries, first to find the user and then to find the group based on the user.

Comment: @BillyChan why can't a question have invalid code or even no code at all for that matter? Concepts can be discussed without code. Questions can be asked about concepts.

Comment: Ben, sorry if my words sounds not polite. But your question looks not so serious. If an item belongs to user, at least user should have many items? Why can't you write that in question? Or this lack of another side is also part of the edge case? Why can't you show full group association? Edge case is not wrong, but it would be better to keep all other parts clear and static.

Comment: Billy, I chose to add the least amount of pseudocode as was necessary to understand the question. I did this because it makes for less reading for other stackoverflow users. I did not think the other associations are relevant. If user has_many items or has_one item is irrelevant to the question. The question directly pertains to whether or not having duplicate data and therefore the possibility of having loss of data integrity is a justifiable tradeoff if one gains query performance and simpler queries.

Comment: has_one and has_many does matter, you just have not noticed it. Anyway I have to admit I have difficulty to understand your question as well as the design.

Comment: If you can explain to me why has_one or has_many does matter to the question, please do so...you are right, I do not understand why it matters.

Comment: Regarding the differences between #2 and #3, I believe that in #3 you're just saying that item.group should be calculated by calling the group method on the item's user. To do that, it has to first run a query to instantiate the user object, and then calling the group method causes it to run the second query. So between #2 and #3, #2 uses one less query AND does not instantiate the user object, which is also a plus if you don't need the user for anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a question of valid trade-offs. Strictly speaking, in a fully normalized database your items table wouldn't have a group column, instead it would always go through the users table to find the group. That has the least amount of duplication, and thus the highest data integrity, but at the cost of doing that extra join every time you want to find an item's group. I'm assuming that a user also only belongs to one group. If a user can belong to many groups, then I think you would have to have that items.group_id column to know to which of those groups an item belongs.

If you want the faster query performance on lookup, you can keep the extra association like you have, and add an extra before_* hook to make sure that item.group_id = item.user.group_id, and raise a validation error if they don't match. This would make validating/inserting slightly slower, but would maximize your data integrity and still let you get slightly better performance when reading from the database.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the kind of commentary I'm looking for. And yes, in this example, a user can only belong to a single group.

Comment: Note that the `has_many :through` pattern is often applicable in this case (if you choose not to denormalize the data) - if User `belongs_to` Group and Item `belongs_to` User, you can also say that Item `has_one :group, :through => :user`. Then you can call `.group` on an Item, and get the group of its associated user.

Comment: @MrTheWalrus: thanks, that raises some further issues for me, editing the original question.